# Xamarin separate controls by lines

Tags: xamarin

How do i separate controls by a line in axml file ? Currently i'm putting a textview and give it a height of 3dp and set a background color, i order to imitate the line that i'm talking about. Here is my code :

```
  <TextView
        android:text="Disable vibration"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2.3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Disble sound alert"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
```

The problem with this code is that the line becomes very thick, and if i reduce the height to 1dp then the line doesn't show up. I want the line to look like the lines in the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a TextView use a View. Something like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

between your TextViews should work.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you